# Can you post the same product in more than 21 groups in Facebook buy/sell groups with the post in several groups feature?

Tags: facebook-groups

In Facebook groups which uses the buy/sell template, they added the feature to post the same product in several groups at the same time. But when I try to mark more than 21 groups, it raises a message which says "you reached the maximum number of groups you can post this product" or something like that. But in my list of selling products, there are some products that Facebook shows me they have been posted in 40 groups or so. How is this possible if when I try to do this with a new product it doesnt let me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has changed this limit and now you can definetely post in more than 21 groups, apparently in as many groups as you want